# Get relative position to root

Tags: python, scripting

Hi I need to get the knee position relative to the root in the attached [image]

Right now I use

`local_mat = ob.convert_space(pose_bone=pbone, matrix=pbone.matrix, from_space='POSE', to_space='LOCAL')`  and `local_mat.to_translation()` to get the position, but it's all 0. Is there a way to do this in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
obj.pose.bones['Bone'].head
```

gets bone position in object space (relative to object's root)

Comment: Is it possible to get the relative pose with the second bone's head instead of root?

Comment: Aha, just subtract that vector should be good